# How to dependent dropdown with Laravel Inertia Vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have AddressController, and inside that controller, i have function loadCity with other CRUD function like this:

```
public function loadCities(Request $request)
    {
            $provinceId = $request->province_id;
            $cities = Province::where('province_id', $provinceId)->get();

            return response()->json($cities);
    }
```

And my create.vue script:

```
<Multiselect v-model="form.province_id" :options="provinces" valueProp="id" label="name" trackBy="name" :searchable="true" placeholder="Select:" @change="loadCities" />

const cities = ref([]); 

const loadCities = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await router.get(`/apps/address/load-cities/${form.province_id}`);
        cities.value = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

and this is my route web.id:

```
Route::resource('/address', AddressController::class, ['as' => 'apps'])
    ->middleware('permission:address.index|address.create|address.edit|address.delete')
    ->except(['show']);

        Route::get('/address/load-cities/{province_id}', [AddressController::class, 'loadCities'], ['as' => 'apps'])
        ->name('apps.address.loadCities');
```

But the problem now is error:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
```

Can i create dependent dropdown using intertia router like this? Or i have something missing with my code? Thanks before.

Update:
if i console.log(form.province_id) its return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes file, define the loadCities route using the get method:

```
 Route::get('/address/load-cities/{province_id}', [AddressController::class, 'loadCities'])->name('apps.address.loadCities');
```

In your create.vue script, update the loadCities method to make a GET request to the correct route:

```
const loadCities = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await router.get(`/address/load-cities/${form.province_id}`); // Update the route
        cities.value = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

You can ensure that the loadCities function is called only after the province_id has been selected. You can achieve this by listening to the input event on the Multiselect component.

```
<Multiselect v-model="form.province_id" :options="provinces" valueProp="id" label="name" trackBy="name" :searchable="true" placeholder="Select:" @input="handleProvinceChange" />
```

Then, define the handleProvinceChange method in your Vue component:

```
const handleProvinceChange = async () => {
    // Check if the province_id is not null or undefined
    if (form.province_id) {
        await loadCities(); // Call the loadCities function
    }
}
```

Ensure that the loadCities method is defined above the handleProvinceChange method to avoid any reference issues.

In your Vue component, create a watcher for the form.province_id property:

```
watch: {
  'form.province_id': {
    immediate: true, // Call the handler immediately after the component is created
    handler(newProvinceId, oldProvinceId) {
      if (newProvinceId) {
        loadCities(); // Call the loadCities function when the province_id changes
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, i have do that in my code. Then i found a main problem is, the form.province_id is null when i do action change with my multiselect

Comment: @ASHafizullah Ensure that the form.province_id is being set correctly before making the request. You mentioned that console.log(form.province_id) returns null, so you may need to investigate why the province_id is not being set properly in your Vue component.
you can use alert(form.province_id);

Comment: I think its about event timing, the value of province_id get from multiselect is delay. When i first change select, its return null, when i do second select action, then the first value of province_id that i selected before will printed in console log

Comment: @ASHafizullah I edited my answer. check and keep me posted pls

Comment: thanks for your update, i have try that. But the result is still same, delay one action like i mentioned earlier

Comment: add watcher mate, check my answer again pls and keep me posted

Comment: You can remove the @change="loadCities" event from the Multiselect component as the watcher will handle the province_id changes.

Comment: perfecto, thank you so much bro. I implement your code with a little improvement